# How to inherit cookies from another class

Tags: c#, cookies, c#-4.0, c#-5.0, c#-6.0

I have 2 c# class: Login and getpage

Both the class has own methods and both have own cookie container

Methods use cookie containers

Getpage class inherits login

Now the question is since I declared container and it is used by login class - all the methods share the cookies. No problem but when I want to use those cookies in inherited getpage class I get no cookies..

What is wrong? 
How can I use inherited cookies?

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, there is a cookie container in both your classes i.e. Parent (Login) and Child (GetPage) classes. Since you have not initialized the cookie container of GetPage, it does not have any cookie information in it and when you try to get the cookie information inside GetPage methods, they access the cookie container of GetPage and not Login class.

Therefore, to access the Cookie Container of Login class in GetPage, you need to use the 'base' keyword inside the methods of GetPage.

This way you should be able to use the cookie information stored within the Login class's cookie container within GetPage also.